# Changing an image src on the fly with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, onerror

I'm trying to change the `src` of some `img` tags if/when there is a problem with the pics when loading the page.  I seem to be getting some random behavior particularly from Internet Explorer 9.  Some of the images show the replaced image correctly and some have a red cross on them.  If I debug in the browser I'm told that `ImgError()` is not defined.  It's clearly defined in the code and is obviously working.  Why is this happening?

```
<div class="PhotoBorder"><img alt="" onerror="imgError(this)" 
    src="./images/services/69_Staffmember.jpg" /></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">           
    </script>  

<script> 
$(window).load( function() {
    $('.RowWrapper').each(function() {
        var TotalWidth = 0;
        $(this).find('.StaffMember').each(function() {
            TotalWidth = TotalWidth + $(this).outerWidth(true);     
        });
        this.style.width = TotalWidth + "px";           
    });
});

function imgError(img)
{ 
    img.setAttribute("src","./images/services/49_ImgMissing.jpg");  
    img.removeAttribute("onerror");
}     

</script>
```

Comment: TotalWidth.toString() + "px";

Comment: The script defining *ImgError* must be **before** any code that calls it. HTML is parsed and "executed" sequentially.

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: @RobG  Your suggestion seemed to work.  Please submit an answer and I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering on behalf of RobG.  The definition of imgError() was below where it was being called in my code.  You must position your code definitions above where you make calls in your html.  Otherwise your results may be undefined as I found out.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you're getting the error that `ImgError() is not defined` it's because your function name is `imgError`, not `ImgError()`.

But, if that was a typo in your question then it's possible that you're getting the error `imgError() is not defined` at some points because chances are the image is being requested from the cache and it's error handler is firing instantaneously - i.e. before the rest of your document has been parsed meaning that your `imgError` function is not yet available. To fix it, just put your `imgError` function in a script tag in the head of your document.

Comment: Yes that was just a typo in the question.

Comment: Wow, seriously?  I am using a content management system.  I don't have access to the head section of the page.

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of document.ready or even window.load??  The document is supposed to be ready to work on.

Comment: @PaulMatthews - what part of your code has anything to do with `$(window).load`? the onerror attribute fires when there's an error requesting the image. That may be immediately or after a delay. Additionally, your `imgError()` function isn't inside any `$(window).load` (not that it would make a difference).

Answer (score 0):

Give your image element an id and try this:

```
document.getElementById("imageid").src="./images/services/49_ImgMissing.jpg";
```

Comment: Can't use IDs because there are many images.  The code is designed to work for each individual one.

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: @jp310 I think he is using jQuery based from the script code

Comment: or you can try: $(".your_class").attr("src","your_src");

Comment: I use jQuery in my code as you can see but not for this.  I simply use the onError attribute to call the ImgError() function.

Comment: I'm not really sure how that would change what's happening??

Comment: Did you check this out:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc197053(v=vs.85).aspx